# Unchecking all the rows in px-data-table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, polymer-1.0, predix

I am using [px-data-table](https://www.predix-ui.com/#/elements/data-table/px-data-table) in an Angular2 application.
The data-table is used as follows:

```
<px-data-table #myTableRef [tableData]='tableDetails' language="en" (px-row-click)="selectedChanged($event)" (px-select-all-click)="selectAll($event)" sortable selectable show-column-chooser>
    <px-data-table-column *ngFor="let header of headers" type="html" name="{{header.value}}" label="{{header.label}}" [disableHide]="header.disableHide" [hide]="!header.disableHide">
    </px-data-table-column>
</px-data-table>
```

The user selects more than one rows. So selectedChanged($event) is fired and multiple rows are selected. Now I'd like the selected rows to be unchecked from code not via user interaction. I went with the following approaches (which did not work):

1. Fire event 'px-select-all-click' from Angular by:

   ```
   this.myTableRef.nativeElement.fire('px-select-all-click')
   this.myTableRef.nativeElement.fire('px-select-all-click', this.myTableRef.nativeElement.selectedRows)
   // also did a ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() after injection but it did not work.
   ```
2. Select the checkbox with id 'selectAllCheckbox' from Angular by:

   ```
   this.myTableRef.nativeElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('selectAllCheckBox')
   this.myTableRef.nativeElement.querySelector('selectAllCheckbox')
   //returns null in both cases so I can't do a .click() on it
   ```
3. Empty the selectedRows attribute:

   ```
   this.myTableRef.nativeElement.selectedRows = [];
   ```

All three methods don't work.
I was looking inside the aha-table.html imported inside the px-data-table.html and found a convenient method: `_setAllRows(e)` which unselects all the rows with `_setAllRows(false)`. If only this was exposed or I could call this from Angular, I'd have my solution to the problem: unchecking the selected rows.

Any solutions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After noticing that the `_setAllRows(e)` is a method of `aha-table` which is a component nested under `px-data-table` component, accessing the method is easy according to the Polymer documentation for [Local DOM API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding).

```
let tableRef = this.myTableRef.nativeElement;
tableRef.$$('aha-table')._setAllRows(false);
```

Basically `$$('selector')` is the Polymer shorthand for dynamically created nodes. If I get the reference for the `aha-table` node, I can call its methods.